# auto reload content of a postgreSQL table

Tags: java, php, database, postgresql

I am using this code:

[my code](http://paste.ofcode.org/B95k2YPVqVJFHMFMYpw6AY)

to output my table. My question is how is possible to updating it in the page without reloading?

Thank you

Comment: Please read the [help]. Code should be included in the question itself, not in a link to some other site.

Answer (score 0):

Either use **AJAX** requests or if you feel good, try **HTML5 websockets** : add a `trigger` to the table `UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE`, and keep your clients up-to-date.

**AJAX** means you'll be doing a request from client to server every few seconds, to check if anything have changed and if so, you'll download the new data (usually devs use JSON), and update your table using javascript with this data.

With **websockets**, the event starts server side : whenever the db table is updated, you send a request from the server to the clients to tell them to update the table with the new data.

You'll find plenty of examples on the web, searching either for **AJAX** or **websockets**.

If you don't know what they are, I'd recommend you to go for **AJAX**, as setting-up a **websockets server** with **PHP** might be tricky.

Comment: I am afraid you missunderstood me. I just want to update the output of the table in realtime. So if it changes itt will be displayed instantly in the webpage.

EDIT

"AJAX means you'll be doing a request from client to server every few seconds"

I need to refresh the output at least 2 in a second, is that possible?

Comment: Then what you are looking for is triggers and websockets. I didn't misunderstand, and as far as I know it's the only solution.
Though if you don't need the "instantly" part, try AJAX, it's simpler.